# why $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+f(x,y)\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0 \Rightarrow f(x,y) \equiv \text{constant}$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Assume $f(x,y) \in C^{(1)}(\Bbb{R}^2)$, if$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+f(x,y)\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$$. Show that $f(x,y) \equiv \text{constant}$

---

My approach:

For every solution of $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{dx}}=f(x,y)$, we have $$\frac{\text{d}f(x,y(x))}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\partial f(x,y(x))}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f(x,y(x))}{\partial y}\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\equiv0$$ then $f(x,y)\equiv \text{constant}$ in its any solution curve: $y=y(x)$. But in its different solution curves, does they equal the same value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what those solution curves are. Since they satisfy $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ and $f$ is constant along the curve, the slope is constant. It's a line of slope $f(x,y)$. If two of these lines have different slopes, they must intersect; what would $f$ be equal to at the intersection?